# JSON/PHP Array to MYSQL insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, insert

I have a JSON array that I convert to a PHP array resulting in a series of IDs such as:

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => 2343
      [1] => 4345
      [2] => 4432
      [3] => 3456
   )
```

I would like to insert these image IDs into the database with a common gallery ID - Here is how it would look if I was to write each query individually:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('2343', '1')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('4345', '1')";
$query3 = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('4432', '1')";
$query4 = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('3456', '1')";
```

How would I somehow loop this to make it as simple an efficient as possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ";
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $sql .= "('$id', '1'),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
```

Comment: It took me a while to work out what you where doing here - but it worked like a charm, and simple. Thanks, nauphal.

Answer (score 2):

It's time to use prepared Statements!

```
$pdo = new \PDO('...');
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES (?, '1')");
foreach ($data_array as $value)
    $sth->execute(array($value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array. Ex.:

```
 foreach ($your_array as $item){
     $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES (%d,1)",$item);
     //Now execute query
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

in simple

```
foreach ($id_array as $id) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('$id', '1')";
  // execute your query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach( (array) $data_arr as $key => $value )
{
$query = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('$value', '1')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way will be using implode func to create whole query at once. Try something like this: `$query = "INSERT INTO gallery_media (media_id, gallery_id) VALUES ('".implode("','1'),",$vals_array)."')";`